# Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.DateTimeOffset?'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Just trying to get a list that does have data in one of my view models. I have got so that if there is NO data it lists but I did it so that it does have data.

It's just throwing the error in the title. Here is the code listing:

```
    public List<RegisterMark> HasRegistered
        => RegisterMarks
            .Where(rm => rm.TimeRegistered is true)
            .ToList();
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reformulate the where expression to test for non-null:

```
.Where(rm => rm.TimeRegistered != null)
```

The reason:
When a property is not set, it either has a default value or is `null`. If its the latter, you can simply test for it.

Do note `is` is only used in c# to do a type comparison.

Comment: Thank you Stefan - So easy when you see it!!

Comment: Aside: `is` is also used for constant pattern matching. Ie: `x is 5` of `x is "value"`

Comment: Ah, yes,  "new" feature isnt it? XD